# upload image to specified folder

Tags: mysql, spring-mvc

I am using spring mvc 3.0,jsp,mysql. I have table tbl_employee and it's attributes are
emp_id(int)
address(string)
image(string)
Now, I want the form to be displayed that can get the image of particular employee and store the image location in image field of database and store image in the particular folder of sytem, How, can I do this. Can anybody provide me with some example??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try a jquery based image uploader and you should be good to go . You can use valum-uploader or bluecraft